# In BIRT, how do I access the children of a cell from the cell's event script blocks

Tags: cell, reporting, birt

I am creating images dynamically in [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) and adding them to a cell of a grid.  The grid is part of a List, which iterates over the records in the data source.

I want to be able to modify the properties of the images on a per-record basis.  Specifically I am changing the margins - but my problem is that I cannot find the way to access the contents of the cell.

I expected that I could use the 'this' keyword in the cell's **`onRender`** function and it would provide me a [handle to access the cell's contents](http://www.birt-exchange.com/documentation/BIRT_220/EngineJavadoc/model/api/org/eclipse/birt/report/model/api/CellHandle.html#getContent()).

This function does not seem to work though - it is apparently a different object type.

How do I access the children of an individual instance of a cell?